SyntaxError: No number after minus sign in JSON at position 1 (line 1 column 2) through POST request in Postman
When I use my API on my website application it works perfectly fine, however when I try testing it in Postman I get SyntaxError: No number after minus sign in JSON at position 1 (line 1 column 2). I've put the data into the body in Postman and made sure that the names are correct but the error still persists. The weird thing is, I only get this with POST request. My GET and DELETE requests work fine from Postman. The JSON response after adding the product to the basket from the website is:
{
id: 70,
productId: 21,
userId: 10,
size: 'Medium',
customerQuantity: 1
}
But when I use postman put the required data in body it gives the error in the title
The API code:
import prisma from "@/app/prismadb";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: Request) {
    const body = await request.json();
    const { productId, userId, size, customerQuantity } = body;

   

    try {
        const existingCartItem = await prisma.basket.findFirst({
            where: {
                productId,
                userId,
                size: {
                    contains: size, 
                }
            },
        });

        if (existingCartItem) {
            await prisma.basket.delete({
                where: {
                    id: existingCartItem.id,
                },
            });
        }

        const product = await prisma.basket.create({
            data: {
                productId,
                userId,
                size,
                customerQuantity
            },
        });

        return NextResponse.json(product);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error adding product to cart", error);
        return NextResponse.error();
    }
}

export async function DELETE(request: Request) {
    const body = await request.json();
    const { productId, userId } = body;

    try {
        const deleteItem = await prisma.basket.deleteMany({
            where: {
                productId: productId,
                userId: userId,
            },
        });

        return NextResponse.json(deleteItem);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error deleting product", error);
        return NextResponse.error();
    }
}





Well what is the broken JSON content? That's where the error is but you didn't post it.

There is no broken JSON content where it puts the data into the table, I did a console log of product and it gave me this as a response
{
id: 70,
productId: 21,
userId: 10,
size: 'Medium',
customerQuantity: 1
}

Your entire question is based on a JSON syntax error; how an you say there's no broken JSON content?

I'm not sure what the problem is with the JSON syntax error but if the console log of JSON response is showing perfectly fine then I don't know what else could be the issue.

Made a silly mistake, the API was expecting JSON data in the request body and not form-data as I was doing in Postman. Changing it to raw instead of form-data and selecting JSON from dropdown menu fixed the problem.

You don't show what exactly you are putting in the postman body, but if you are putting in what you call the "JSON response", that will give you an error, since it is not JSON. It is a Javscript object, but not valid JSON.
You would need to change your:

{ id: 70, productId: 21, userId: 10, size: 'Medium', customerQuantity: 1 }

to

{ "id": 70, "productId": 21, "userId": 10, "size": 'Medium', "customerQuantity": 1 }


Close, but 'Medium' should have double quotes.  Single quotes are not valid JSON either.
